# How to bind database with dropdownlist in MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I tried to bind the database with dropdown using IEnumerable. But it showing error which is showed in the below image.

[image]

**My Model (CustomerViewModel)**

```
 public Nullable<System.Guid> AreaID { get; set; }
 public string Area { get; set; }
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AreaList { get; set; }
```

**My Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Create ()
    {
        CustomerViewModel cvm = new CustomerViewModel();
        cvm.AreaList = db.Areas.Where(a => a.IsDeleted == false).Select(a => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = a.AreaID.ToString(),
            Text = a.DisplayName
        });
        return View();
   }
```

**My View Code**

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Area, new { @class = "control-label" })
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AreaID, Model.AreaList, "Please select a Area", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: The exception is pretty clear. What do **you** think it means?

Comment: Actually i didn't understand the meaning of the error so only i post here steen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have works ok. The problem is that you are creating a query where you use the `.ToString()` method, which cannot be translated to a DB equivalent syntax.

To make it work, you need to select the items from DB using `.ToList()`, and after that create the `SelectListItem`

```
cvm.AreaList = db.Areas.Where(a => a.IsDeleted == false).ToList().Select(a => new SelectListItem()
{
      Value = a.AreaID.ToString(),
      Text = a.DisplayName
});
```

Comment: Is there is any mistake in my view code ? Because it showing error in view code//

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_1oipvwve.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You need to pass the model to the view. `return View(cvm);`

Comment: Yes I forgot to do that . Ok i have  a check again.

Comment: Thanks its working. any like to know ny another method is there except this ienumerable and viewbag to bind the database with dropdown?